# How to calculate the quantum Volume?

Tags: quantum-volume

I read [the article of IBM](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/650c/3fa2a231cd77cf3d882e1659ee14175c01d5.pdf) on Quantum Volume, but I don't understand how to calculate the *effective error rate*, and therefore the Quantum Volume.

Can someone give an example of the calculation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of using Qiskit to benchmark quantum devices using the Quantum Volume metric. It generates the quantum volume model circuits, compiles them, runs them, and fits the result to find the volume.

The source code for how the fitting is done is here:
https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ignis/blob/master/qiskit/ignis/verification/quantum_volume/fitters.py