# Is there a straightforward way to calculate the quantum volume for simple systems?

Tags: experimental-realization, ibm-quantum-devices, quantum-volume, metrics

There are a few people who ask how to calculate IBM's "quantum volume", but it's not clear what the actual mathematical definition of this is. In the answers [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6588/how-to-calculate-the-quantum-volume), people just point to running some program, which is not helpful for understanding or comparing with other technologies.

Is there a straightforward way of calculating this for a simple system?

For example, if I have n-1qubit gates with efficiency of 1, m-2qubit gates with efficiency B, and complete connectivity between qubits - what would my quantum volume be?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the calculation steps are quite complex to give a simple formula or even to follow it by hand.

Maybe this [medium article](https://medium.com/qiskit/what-is-quantum-volume-anyway-a4dff801c36f)  and the cited [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.08571.pdf) gives you a better general understanding.
As you can see in the article and paper, QV takes into account various factors other than error rates e.g. calibration and circuit optimization.

> IBM successfully ran this exact test to achieve a Quantum Volume of 64 on its 27 qubit “Montreal” system — and the test didn’t even require building a new device. Instead, the team incorporated improvements to the Qiskit compiler, refined the calibration of the two-qubit gates, and issued upgrades to the noise handling and readout based on tweaks to the microwave pulses and gates before they’re applied in the circuit.

Other [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.12926.pdf)

> This
> metric takes into account all relevant hardware parameters. This includes the performance parameters (coherence, calibration errors, crosstalk, spectator errors, gate
> fidelity, measurement fidelity, initialization fidelity) as
> well as the design parameters such as connectivity and
> gate set. **It also includes the software behind the circuit optimization**.

The simplest explanation from medium article would be:
 *2 to the power of the depth of the largest square circuit (width=depth), which you were able to run on your device successfully with greater than two-thirds probability and confidence interval greater than 97.725%, gives you QV.*

Comment: okay so loosely speaking, a quantum volume of 64 suggests a 8 qubits and 8 gates at 97% fidelity (and 2/3 efficiency?)

Comment: Not completely! QV 64 means the largest circuit you've been able to run on your device had 6 qubits and depth 6. Depth 6 means the circuit had 6 computational septs (not gates).  
The probability and confidence here, refer to the correctness of the output bit-string of the circuit and not the gates.

Comment: What is the difference between a computational step and a gate?

Comment: By 6 computational steps I meant `depth=6`. https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/how-to-calculate-circuit-depth-properly#:~:text=The%20circuit%20depth%20is%20the,in%20time%20along%20qubit%20wires.

Answer (score 1):

To put in simple words, the quantum volume tells a maximal dimension of state space (Hilbert space) you can simulate on a quantum computer sucessfully. For example, quantum volume 64 means that you can simulate systems with 64 states, i.e. represened by 6 qubits ($6 = \log_2 64$). Moreover, maximal depth of your simulation (circuit) has to be less or equal 6.

*Note that this is relatively rough description what the quantum volume is, however, I think it is sufficient for basic understanding what that means.*

Comment: Nice perspective!